# Metric tensor for just one index

Tags: geometry, tensors

I'm novice in the territory of tensor calculus. I know the utilization of the metric tensor to transform the covariant basis to contravariant one, vice versa:

$Z^i = Z^{ij}Z_j$  ***(Eq. 1)***

I am going to set the both indices, similarly, by $i$:

$Z^i = Z^{ii}Z_i$  ***(Eq. 2)***

Would you please explain below staffs in a ***geometrical perspective***:

- the comparison between ***Eq.1*** & ***Eq.2***?
- the interpretation of the tensor: $Z^{ii}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $Z_j$  the one form $Z(e_j,\cdot)$? If it is something different u should rename it

Comment: $Z^{ii} Z_i$ is not a tensor. It's gibberish.

Comment: @Muphrid: I am going to find $\frac{Z^i}{Z_i}$. How do you evaluate that?